# how can we create edge route in ROSA (Red Hat OpenShift Service on AWS)?

Tags: https, openshift

I have a vendor http service in rosa openshift that I'd like to have https encryption. I use LoadBalancer type service to make it accessible in internet. ROSA creates external IP as *.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com. The name is more than 64 bit long hence I can only create csr in this way:

openssl req -new -key key.key -out csr.csr -subj "/CN=*.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com"
then 'oc create route edge --service test-http --hostname test-https.elb.amazonaws.com --key key.key --cert crt.crt' but this does not work.
How can I enable https in ROSA?

Comment: Can you provide any error messages, what you're seeing, what you expect to see? It's very hard to help troubleshoot with minimal information. Also, ROSA comes with Red Hat support, you should be able to reach out at https://access.redhat.com/support for help as well.

Comment: as @WillGordon pointed out, you need to add some more details here.

What exactly are you running?
What is the output exactly?
What did you expect to happen and what happened instead?